# How to calculate with php the total with a VAT percentage in PHP

Tags: php, percentage

Im trying to make a calculation with the following values:

- Product cost (without VAT) = 12,40 ($product)
- The VAT percentage = 21%, what I will store in the database as 0,21 ($vat_perc)
- The VAT is 2,604 ($vat)

edit: The VAT is per product

When I try to get the total then I get 15,00 ($total)

What I did is the following:

```
$total = $product + $vat
```

This will echo 15.004

Then I use the number_format:

```
echo(number_format($total,2,',','.'));
```

This will print 15.00

But then I want to multiply the product with 2

So that will give the following calculation:

```
$total = $product * 2 + $vat
```

Then again I use the format:

```
echo(number_format($total,2,',','.'));
```

Then the total = 30,01

I tried serveral things like ROUND en INT, but with no succes.

What am I doing wrong in this?  In know that the VAT is the evil one here but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: `$product * 2 + $vat` is this formula correct btw?

Comment: @DavidThomas: correct, I changed the title, thanks!

Comment: @zerkms the VAT is per product.

Comment: in that expression it's per purchase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$tax = round( ($price / 100) * 3.8, 2);`
tax is rounded price  divided by the 100 to make a clear percentage. Multiplied by the wanted stack
then you do the addition to or from your price table.

Well good to have you on the phone - maybe we can solve this faster by phone. Thank god for phones!

Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

Your initial total is 15.004 so when you call `number_format` that gets rounded down to 15.00.  Now when you multiply by 2 your total is `15.008` which `number_format` will round up to 15.01.  The issue isn't with the addition it is with the multiplication by 2.  `number_format` rounds to the nearest place which for your case would be 30.01.

If you want the number to be rounded down all the time use [`floor`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php), like so:

```
$total = floor(($product * 200)) / 100 + $vat;
echo(number_format($total,2,',','.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of how the numbers are rounded with PHP functions.

```
$product = 12.40;
$vat = 2.644;
$total = ( $product + $vat ) * 2;

var_dump( $total );  // float(30.088)
var_dump( number_format($total,2,',','.') );  // string(5) "30,09", rounded 
var_dump( round( $total, 2 ) );  // float(30.09), rounded
var_dump( sprintf('%0.2f', $total ) );  // string(5) "30.09", rounded
var_dump( floor( $total * 100 ) / 100 );  //  float(30.08), not rounded
```

All three founctions ( `number_format`, `round`, `sprintf` ) will round the result, to avoid the rounding and discard the decimal part after two decimal points you can use the last example.